# Running a powershell script (.ps1) on startup

Tags: powershell, startup

Scratching my head with this one. Very new to Powershell also.

GOAL: Upon machine start up Powershell Script launches and asks for a computer name, then adds it to the domain, does a clean up and restarts the machine.

Here is my script:

```
$getName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the new name for this computer"
$user = "mdt_join"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $user" -AsSecureString
$username = "bc\mdt_join"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

Add-Computer -NewName $getName -DomainName DOMAIN -OUPath "OU=Managed Stations,DC=DC,DC=DC,DC=DC" -Credential $credential -restart

Rename-Computer –NewName $getName

Remove-Item C:\Users\ladmin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startup.cmd

Remove-Item $MyINvocation.InvocationName
```

This script works if I run it manually but when I use this startup.cmd

```
REM   Attempt to set the execution policy by using PowerShell version 2.0 syntax.
PowerShell -Version 2.0 -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\script1.ps1 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU -393216 (
   REM   PowerShell version 2.0 isn't available. Set the execution policy by using the PowerShell version 1.0 calling method.

   PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
   PowerShell .\startup.ps1 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
)

REM   If an error occurred, return the errorlevel.
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

I dont get the same result. It just reverts back to the PS C:> bit. I needed the startup.cmd to run it as unrestricted.

Can someone look over this and see where I am going wrong? Go easy with me - I only started dabbling in powershell yesterday.

Comment: I haven't done much testing with your bit of code but from what I know about powershell execution policy, it is made to prevent it being changed by a script (hence the purpose). That being said, I'm assuming this is being run on a freshly built computer, in which case you'll need to find another way of modifying the execution policy (registry, local GPO, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Execute PowerShell command below to run the PowerShell script **`.ps1`** through the **task scheduler** at user login.

```powershell
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TASKNAME" -Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon) -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "${Env:WinDir}\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -Command `"& 'C:\PATH\TO\FILE.ps1'`"") -RunLevel Highest -Force;
```

> **`-AtLogOn`** - indicates that a trigger starts a task when a user logs on.
>
> **`-AtStartup`** - indicates that a trigger starts a task when the system is started.

**`-WindowStyle Hidden`** - don't show PowerShell window at startup. **Remove if not required.**

**`-RunLevel Highest`** - run PowerShell as administrator. **Remove if not required.**

**P.S.**

> **If necessary execute PowerShell command below to enable PowerShell scripts execution.**

```powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force;
```

**`Bypass`** - nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts.

**`Unrestricted`** - loads all configuration files and runs all scripts. If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the internet, you're prompted for permission before it runs.

Comment: How to run that only once? After delete the file

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm is it something as simple as adding some switches when your calling powershell

`Powershell -noninteractive -nologo .\startup.ps1`

Also, `.\startup.ps1` assumes that script is in the directory that powershell is started in (guessing C:), to be safe i'd either `CD` to the script location, or just use full path ie. `Powershell -noninteractive -nologo C:\Scripts\startup.ps1`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a powershell profile script which is executed everytime powershell starts up.  I found this link; http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_profile_ps1.htm, which tells you how to create and manage PS profile script.

Within the script you can append startup scripts and assign scripts to variable names so they act the same as environment variables in command prompt.

So in your case just add the script to the beginning of the profile script for it to be executed when powershell startup.